# Two columns with centered text flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to have two columns with centered contend with the same height with no matter what amount of content is filled in any of columns. So far I achieved this:

```
<div class="call-outs-container">
<div class="call-out">
<h4> 1</h4>
</div>
<div class="call-out">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam 
obcaecati vel, placeat numquam omnis sit consectetur nobis molestias! 
Explicabo deserunt placeat numquam omnis.It is a long established fact that 
a reader will be distracted by the     readable content of a page when 
looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-
or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, 
content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop
publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their 
default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web 
sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, 
sometimes by accident, sometimes
on purpose (injected humour and the like). It is a long established fact 
that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when 
looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-
or-less normal distribution
of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look 
like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors 
now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem 
ipsum' will uncover
many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over 
the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and 
the like).</p>
</div>
</div>
.call-outs-container {
 max-width: 1400px;
 margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
 }

.call-out {
padding: 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
.call-outs-container {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
}

.call-out:nth-child(1) {
background-color: #c0dbe2;
flex: 1;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
}
.call-out:nth-child(2) {
background-color: #cdf1c3;
flex: 5;
}
```

The thing is that I want the columns to be the same height with centered content. Using margin auto for the first column, center the content but make it smaller in height.

Comment: The dupe solves this perfect, so I deleted my answer